# An editor or IDE with a particular function

Tags: text-editor

I am searching for an IDE or a small editor which have an ability to "allocate some part of code to a new tab".

Lets say i have a 1000 line file. 
I want to quickly edit just one method - 30 lines for example.
I mark these 30 lines, click something and i am editing these lines in a new tab.
And when i have edition finished, it applies to a 1000line file.

I am using mainly Linux but if there is something windows-only program i will test it and give a shot for windows.
Please help me (:

Answer (score 2):

> I am searching for an IDE or a small editor which have an ability to "allocate some part of code to a new tab".

This feature should be easy to implement in any scriptable editor. For example it took me less than a minute to write the following [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor *Lua* macro that does exactly what you describe:

```
function key_macro()
    screen_update_disable()
    MarkCopyEx()
    FileNew()
    MarkPasteSmart()
    screen_update_enable()
    screen_update()
end

key_macro() -- run the macro
```

Zeus is a Windows based editor, but as I said before, this should be very easy to implement in any scriptable editor.

Answer (score 1):

1. Files this large should be refactored and split anyway ;)
2. What's wrong with editing it in-place if you're going to merge it anyway? It's not like the editor will scale the font size to fit those 1000 lines onto your screen (right?!?)...
3. In case you desperately want a clear screen, about every editor should be able to quickly create a new file, let you copy, paste and edit the method there and let you copy it back. Yes, not as shiny as full IDE integration, but again: Why do you want to do this and why is it necessary?

Comment: Because i don't want to lose focus.